# How to create a component at runtime, equivalent to design time

Tags: delphi, components, runtime

I want to create a TscStyledForm component at runtime instead of placing it on form at design time. (This component from www.almdev.com fixes some VCL Styles issues)

If I create in the Form constructor (as below), the behaviour is slightly different to that of design time component (Titlebar font is not correct):

```
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FStyledForm: TscStyledForm;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;
...

{ TForm2 }

constructor TForm2.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FStyledForm := TscStyledForm.Create(Self);
end;
```

If I create the component in CreateWnd, that also does not solve the problem.

Is it possible to simulate the creation of design time component precisely in runtime?

Comment: You probably need to ask the developer

Answer (score 2):

If you install [GExperts](https://blog.dummzeuch.de/experimental-gexperts-version/) in your Delphi, you can create the component visually, and then right click it and select "Components to code". This will generate the Pascal source code that is equivalent to the current settings of the visually created component.